# Пунктуация при уточнении (местоимение + сущ)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложение

Пример: "*Куда он подевался этот слесарь?*"
Вопрос: нужна ли запятая перед "этот"? Вроде как да, но уверенности нет.

Answer (score 1):

**Куда он подевался, этот слесарь?**

"Этот слесарь" — приложение при личном местоимении *он*.

> Всегда обособляется приложение при личном местоимении ([Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm))

Примечание. Слова "этот слесарь" выступают как пояснительная конструкция, а не как уточнение. Различие между уточняющими и пояснительными членами предложения заключается в том, что уточнение – это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому, а пояснение – это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.